DLP tool for clipboard analysis
I am currently searching for a DLP solution with the main target of analysing the content copied by the users between the browser and os apps. The tool should cover Mac and Windows devices.
Currently Symantec one caught my attention (a bit worried it cannot control within app data copy-paste) though I am quite interested if you have aby experience with os level solutions (Microsoft Purview, JAMF?)that would allow me to control/block data paste depending on the target app.
If there are any free / opensource solutions that would be even better.
